# Nested iteration over collection

Tags: javascript, iterator, lodash

I am trying to assemble a string using output from two collections. To do that, I iterate over one of them, using _forEach function, and use it's output as an input for another iterator. But I can't make it work.

Code:

```
    const data1 = [{
        label: 'Id',
        data: 'id'
      },
      {
        label: 'First name',
        data: 'first_name'
      },
      {
        label: 'Last name',
        data: 'last_name'
      },
      {
        label: 'IP Address',
        data: 'ip_address'
      },
    ];

const data2 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Robinet",
  "last_name": "Golsby",
  "ip_address": "201.83.127.236"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Kirby",
  "last_name": "Feaver",
  "ip_address": "143.188.49.149"
}]

let keys = '';
const getKeys = _.forEach(data1, value => keys += '' +value.data);

let stringValue = '';
const getStringValue = _.forEach(tableData, value => stringValue += ' ' + value.first_name);
```

So I can get a list of keys from the first object, and I can get the list of values from the second, but only if the key is hardcoded. What I want to do is to iterate over each of the entries in `data2` in the 'outer' iterator, while providing keys to get the values using iteration over `data1`. How do I do that?

Edit: the end result would look like:

`1 Robinet Golsby 201.83.127.236`

Comment: Please add an example of the requested result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like:

```
const result = _.chain(data1)
    .map('data') // get keys from data1
    .thru(keys => _.map(data2, item => _.at(item, keys))) // iterate data2 and get values by keys
    .map(values => _.join(values, ' ')) // values array to string
    .value();
```

result:

```
["1 Robinet Golsby 201.83.127.236", "2 Kirby Feaver 143.188.49.149"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I think that you can achieve your goal using nesting [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls:

```js
const data1 = [{"label":"Id","data":"id"},{"label":"First name","data":"first_name"},{"label":"Last name","data":"last_name"},{"label":"IP Address","data":"ip_address"}];
const data2 = [{"id":1,"first_name":"Robinet","last_name":"Golsby","ip_address":"201.83.127.236"},{"id":2,"first_name":"Kirby","last_name":"Feaver","ip_address":"143.188.49.149"}];

const result = data2.map((obj) => data1.map(({ label, data }) => ({
  label,
  data: obj[data]
})));

console.log(result);
```